# Conversion of Unicode to characters in JavaScript confirm window

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a button like below

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="clicked('R&#233;cup&#233;ration de frigorig&#232;ne')" />
```

and the JavaScript function like below

```
function clicked(s) {           
    confirm( s);
}
```

The above code is working fine. But when i add the attribute from backend to the button like,

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "clicked('R&#233;cup&#233;ration de frigorig&#232;ne')");
```

its displaying the string as it is (The Unicode is not getting converted in confirm box). What is the reason for this!!. And I am not getting a solution for this.

Comment: I maybe wrong but I think the & char has been converted to &amp; on the client side, because you set it from the server-side and it should be converted into the correct html entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do the HTML decoding yourself for the attribute as it looks like ASP.NET automatically converts it for front end code, but doesn't when adding it from back end code:

```
   Button1.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "clicked('" +
     HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("R&#233;cup&#233;ration de frigorig&#232;ne" + "')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the actual unicode character on the serverside and add it as an attribute of the Button1, ASP.NET automatically convert them into the correct HTML entities.

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("ClickMessage", "actual unicode chars not the encoded");
Button1.Attribute.Add("OnClick", "clicked(this.getAttribute('ClickMessage');");
```

In this way, your javascript will still work even if the value contains single/double quotes that may break the script.